# failed to deploy Che using minikube -> ✖ Verify if kubectl is installed → E_REQUISITE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: eclipse, kubectl, minikube, eclipse-che

I want to use Che on my centos VM. I have followed the steps mentioned in Che installation document. but Che fails to deploy.
please find below the steps I followed

1.Installed kubectl
[image]

2.installed minikube
[image]

3.minikube start --addons=ingress --vm=true --memory=8192 --driver=none

4.Installed chectl
[image]

5.chectl server:deploy --platform minikube (FAILED)
[image]

FYI ,kubectl is running
[image]

thanks in advance!

Comment: can you add additional debug info like: `which kubectl`, your OS name, minikube version.

Comment: output of which kubectl is  /usr/local/bin/kubectl

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but I've found two causes for this: (1) kubectl still in your working directory, and (2) wrong version of kubectl.

(1)After installing kubectl, make sure kubectl doesn't exist in the directory you're running the commands from. Despite what 'which kubectl' outputs, it seems chectl tries the current directory first.

(2)Make sure kubectl is within compatibility range of kubernetes. Use the Versions selector on this page to download a compatible version (compatibility described on the page, too): https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-linux/